# How to access all Sites running on WebRole from RoleEntryPoint

Tags: azure, log4net, azure-web-roles, log4net-configuration

We have multiple Sites deployed to a single WebRole.

```
<Sites>
  <Site name="Web">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="EndpointA" endpointName="Internal" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
  <Site name="Web2" physicalDirectory="Web2">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="EndpointB" endpointName="EndpointB" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
</Sites>
```

If I understand correctly you can access the primary Site like for example:

```
public class WebRole : RoleEntryPoint 
{
    public override void Run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // Reconfigure log4net every 10 minutes
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            Thread.Sleep(60000);
        }
    }
}
```

But how can I execute log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure() for every Site running on the WebRole?

BTW

The log4net.config file is stored on Azure blob storage.

Edit:

And log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure() will read the correct log4net blob based on App.config or Web.config. Specifically: a ConfigureFromBlob() was added to the log4net implementation.

If the application is installed on-premise, ConfigureFromFile() will automatically watch the log4net.config file for changes and reconfigure if needed. ConfigureFromUri() and ConfigureFromBlob() cannot do this so the log4net.config changes needs to be reconfigured manually.

For Windows Azure I guess the best place is the Run() method.

Comment: Do you need to have different log4net configurations for every site?

Comment: Yes, we need a separate log4net config for each Site. But even if we would have a single log4net config stored on Azure blob storage, then we still would have the problem of having to reconfigure per Site right?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're configuring your sites to run in different application pools, you will need to instrument log4net global static variable per each application, within individual application's global.asax.cs file

Comment: I don't want to change the application itself (see "Edit" part in the original post). But are you saying I cannot access the individual Sites from RoleEntryPoint?